# Why is √(x²) the same as |x|, instead of ±x?

Tags: exponentiation, radicals, absolute-value

We're being taught about absolute value in maths, and we're told that |x| is the same as √(x²), because √(x²) always gives a positive number. But doesn't √(x²) = ±x, since the expression would have the same value regardless of x's sign?

E.g. √(2²) = 2 or -2, because 2*2=2² and (-2)*(-2)=2², but |2| = 2, not ±2

I guess it makes sense if you do (2²)<sup>1/2</sup> = 2<sup>1</sup>, but can you just do this and ignore the possible negative value?

Comment: By definition $|x| = \pm x$. And square roots can't take negative numbers since we're not working with complex numbers.

Comment: We want $\sqrt x$ to be a function, so by default, we pick one of the solutions (the non-negative one) to ensure that it is a function. There are times we do define $\sqrt x$ as you have. It's about convention, rather than anything mathematical

Comment: @Ajay Absolutely not

Comment: @RushabhMehta I know, from the example we're working with real values

Comment: @Ajay even with real values, this isn't true

Comment: Oh wait, I put 1. I meant x sorry.

Comment: $\sqrt{x^2}$ is a single non-negative value for given $x$, as is $|x|$, while $\pm x$ may be two values and if it is then one of would be negative

Comment: Any positive number $k$ has two square roots, that is, two numbers $x$ such that $x^2 = k$. One will be positive, the other will be its opposite. The symbol $\sqrt k$ is defined to be the *positive* square root only. Yes, $\sqrt k$ is usually called "the square root of $k$", ignoring the existence of the other root. But is because people don't want to remember two names for essentially the same thing, not because it is mathematically sound.